# TokenAutoComplete example: classdef not found error

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, autocompletetextview, android-library

Hi I am trying to integrate tokenautocomplete example by Marshall Weir in my code. When I try running the demo, I get following error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tokenautocomplete.TokenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tokenautocomplete-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.tokenautocomplete-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I have the jar file included from the Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add External Lib.

Still the error exists.

I have also tried including the jar file in lib/libs

Still the error exists.

I have also tried changing the order of gen/src folder in Properties -> order and Export
My order is as follows:
TokenAutoCompleteJar
Gen
SRC
Android 4.0.3
Private Libraries
Dependancies.

Still the error exists.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: am facing the same issue if you fixed the issue plese consider answering your own question I tried using both the library and jar files but no avail

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you resolved this yet and I did accept a pull request to fix some project structure issues a while ago.

If you are still having this issue, you can just grab the core TokenCompleteTextView.java file from the project (https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/tokenautocomplete), modify the package at the top to correspond with your project and use it from there.

Comment: I did fix it. But I would do this anyway.